# Click Event doesn't work when Energy saver is on in Chrome

Tags: vue.js, webpack, nuxt.js

I'm using NuxtJS, when energy saver is on in google chrome, click event doesn't register and doesn't work. No error, it just doesn't work. Any solution?

I tried to work on performance upgrade, but it's 99 on Lighthouse. I tried some ways to preload bundles, or asynchronously load them but none seem to work. Thanks.

Comment: Can I see the website in question? There is not enough information

Comment: A solution to a problem described as "doesn't work" is an impossible task.  We don't know anything about your code.  Please read the post [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), then edit your question to include all details and code relevant to the problem.